# IP hashes a safe alternative to store IP adresses?

Tags: security, forms-authentication

I'd like to put up some tests for users etc, and would like to store the results on an anonymous basis. I am not interested at all to potentially track down users, but on the other hand I need a way to avoid repetitive submissions (within a certain timeframe). So my thought was : why not simply just store a hash of their IP address and check followup submissions against these instead of saving the actual IP address?

It sounds so simple that I am worrying about having missed something, so my questions to the experts is:

- does it provide a relatively safe way to prevent repetitive submissions?
- does it really provide reasonable anonymity for users?
- are there any other caveats or issues I may have missed (like being overly resource intensive etc.)?

thanks..

Comment: [Because an IP address uniquely identifies an individual, right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)? I think the MPAA have a job opening for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> does it provide a relatively safe way to prevent repetitive submissions?

No, users can use a proxy and other approaches to bypass IP checks. Let alone dynamic IP users which can just reset their modems.

> does it really provide reasonable anonymity for users?

Single-way algorithms would provide the best "anonymity", as you technically can't reverse it in an easy way. **Edit:** as rectified by @ta.speot.is, even single-way algorithms can be easily cracked nowadays.

I also don't see why taking "anonymity" to the level of hashing IPs, provided your users are accessing your page through HTTP, your server **WILL** know their IPs and log them in an access log, so, unless someone else has access to your database's stored data, there's not much difference between hashing the IPs or not.

> are there any other caveats or issues I may have missed (like being overly resource intensive etc.)?

A simple hashing function shouldn't take much resources from the server, even though you didn't specify any language in particular. =]

In the end, hashing IPs may be considered a [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) attempt, as it adds no functionality that storing an un-hashed IP already has.

Comment: SHA1 can be calculated at a rate of 2.1B/s http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm Given that there are ~4B IPv4 addresses available I don't think it's going to matter that a hash can't be reversed.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Interesting, I didn't see those numbers before. That's probably faster than googling a rainbow table. :P

Comment: I'm giving 'accepted' for factual correctness and for the time you've been taking for the answer, thanks! To be fair, DmitryK's answer also answered everything I wanted to know, that the solution isn't 'bullet-proof' is something I'm well aware of.

Comment: @richey, I could also provide some solutions if you'd like - but in fact, none are 100%. Blocking all proxies and setting cookies is widely used for to prevent repetitive submission from guests. However, if your guest has cookies disabled and dynamic IP, that's good for nothing. Also blocking proxies would disallow people whom require said tools to access your site (some countries don't have free internet). Another approach is forcing them to register and login to store info in a db, and then we have spambots/floodbots. No solution is 100%.

Answer (score 0):

You are right - storing IP address hashes is better for "anonymity".
Also for the purpose of avoiding repetitive submissions you may also want to take the value of X-Forwarded-For into the consideration too (together with the IP address). Not a panacea but better than just an IP address.